# Kendo UI and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, webpack, vue.js

Hello everyone I'm using the Vue.js CLI

I was following along with this write up: https://65535th.com/jquery-plugins-and-webpack/ about adding in a Jquery plugin to a webpack project.

I installed the expose loader and adding the following line to my webpack.base.conf.js

```
 { test: /jquery/, loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!expose?jquery' }
```

Then in my main.js which is the entry point for the application I added the following two lines to bring the Jquery library in and then bring the Kendo library in.

```
import '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import '../bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js';
```

I then ran npm run dev which kicks everything off and generates the following output (Notice it takes an ungodly amount of time to get back up and going)

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/var/www/public/kendo/bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
webpack: wait until bundle finished: /__webpack_hmr
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/var/www/public/kendo/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
webpack built 6459c5d00452a152a319 in 405389ms
Hash: 6459c5d00452a152a319
Version: webpack 1.13.0
Time: 405389ms
 Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
app.js  14.8 MB       0       app

ERROR in ./bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in /var/www/public/kendo/bower_components/kendo-ui/js
 @ ./bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js 1:1022-1059
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  21.4 kB       0       
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Why is it missing jquery? Is there some sort of configuration that I did wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: check sourcemaps to find where is jQuery's code.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive. I use the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) to define some aliases:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "jQuery": "jquery",
    "$": "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
})
```